# Magento 2: How to stop order from Invoicing Programmatically?

Tags: magento2, orders, custom, invoice, magento2.1.5

I have requirement when done Payment with Paypal using Capture Method.

It automatically creates Invoice.

I need to stop that. How to achieve Programmatically?

Answer (score 3):

In order to *stop create an invoice when customer done Payment with Paypal*.

Then need to rewrite class the model class [**`Magento\Paypal\Model\Ipn`**](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Paypal/Model/Ipn.php#L313) and  stop create invoice at function  [_registerPaymentCapture](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Paypal/Model/Ipn.php#L280)

***di.xml*** at `app/code/[Vendor]/[Modulename]/etc/`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Paypal\Model\Ipn" type="[Vendor]\[Modulename]\Model\Paypal\Ipn" />
</config>
```

### rewrite class Ipn.php

**location:** *app/code/[Vendor]/[Modulename]/Model/Paypal*

```
<?php
/**
 * @category   [Vendor]
 * @package    [Vendor]_[Modulename]
 * @author     Amit Bera <dev.amitbera@gmail.com>
 * @website    http://www.amitbera.com
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */
namespace [Vendor]\[Modulename]\Model\Paypal;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\CreditmemoSender;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender;
use Magento\Paypal\Model\Info;
class Ipn extends \Magento\Paypal\Model\Ipn
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Paypal\Model\ConfigFactory $configFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Adapter\CurlFactory $curlFactory,
         \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory,
        Info $paypalInfo,
        OrderSender $orderSender,
        CreditmemoSender $creditmemoSender,
        $data = array()
    ) {
        parent::__construct($configFactory, $logger, $curlFactory,
                             $orderFactory, $paypalInfo, $orderSender,$creditmemoSender,$data);
    }
    protected function _registerPaymentCapture($skipFraudDetection = false)
    {
        if ($this->getRequestData('transaction_entity') == 'auth') {
            return;
        }
        $parentTransactionId = $this->getRequestData('parent_txn_id');
        $this->_importPaymentInformation();
        $payment = $this->_order->getPayment();
        $payment->setTransactionId(
            $this->getRequestData('txn_id')
        );
        $payment->setCurrencyCode(
            $this->getRequestData('mc_currency')
        );
        $payment->setPreparedMessage(
            $this->_createIpnComment('')
        );
        $payment->setParentTransactionId(
            $parentTransactionId
        );
        $payment->setShouldCloseParentTransaction(
            'Completed' === $this->getRequestData('auth_status')
        );
        $payment->setIsTransactionClosed(
            0
        );
        $payment->registerCaptureNotification(
            $this->getRequestData('mc_gross'),
            $skipFraudDetection && $parentTransactionId
        );
        $this->_order->save();

        // notify customer
        if ($this->_order->getEmailSent()) {
            $this->orderSender->send($this->_order);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: its not work in magento2.3.1

Comment: i am using Paypal Express checkout , i need to stop auto invoice create